# Check if certain column has a duplicate value

Tags: php

```
     Name       Number
1    Benjoe     001
2    Benjoe     002
3    Benjoe     001
```

Given the data, how can I determine that I found duplicate data (Row 1 and 3) using foreach? I have playing with this code right now.

Update: 02/14/2020 - I came up with this algorithm. I've added a flag to determine If I found a duplicate.

```
$results = [
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '002'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
]; 

foreach($results as $log) {
    if($name == $log->vlg_full_name && $number == $log->vlg_contact_number) {
        $isDuplicateNameAndNo = 1;
    } else {
        $isDuplicateNameAndNo = 0;
        break;
    }

    $name = $log->vlg_full_name;
    $number = $log->vlg_contact_number;
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried here.

Comment: Row 2 also duplicates data, namely the name.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I'm playing with the current code right now. I'm editing it when you comment sorry.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware duplicate in both columns only.

Comment: What did you want? Just check if we have duplicate Number + Name?

Comment: You could combine both values and use them as array key. Then you can simply check if an item with that key already exists …

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by a nested loop iterating throug the each element and compating it to the current one.
Try something like that:

```
<?php

$results = [
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '002'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
];

function compare($log1, $log2, $index1, $index2)
{
    return $log1['name'] == $log2['name']
        && $log1['number'] == $log2['number']
        && $index1 != $index2;
}


foreach($results as $index1 => $log1) {
     foreach ($results as $index2 => $log2) {
         if (compare($log1, $log2, $index1, $index2)) {
             echo "Item {$index1} has a duplicate at index {$index2}!<br/>\n";
         }
     }
}
```

Here is a link to working example on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CIdA6)

The output for the above will be:

```
Item 0 has a duplicate at index 2!<br/>
Item 2 has a duplicate at index 0!<br/>
```

If you don't need to exactly know wich items are duplicate you can simply concatenate the values and put them into an array, and check if the value is already there:

```
<?php

$results = [
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '002'],
    ['name' => 'Benjoe', 'number' => '001'],
];

$temp = [];
foreach($results as $index => $log) {
     $val = $log['name'] . '_' . $log['number'];
     if (in_array($val, $temp)) {
         echo "Duplicate found at index {$index}<br/>\n";
     } else {
         $temp[] = $val;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Duplicate found at index 2<br/>
```

Working example on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0ssGC)

If you get your `$results` from database, another approach would be grouping the query by the requried columns and adding the `count(*)` field to gind out how many records exists.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found the quickest way to asnwer my question. I updated my answer.